# SQL Joins are not working properly

Tags: sql, join

I am new to JOINS and testing my query, but it's just not working for me...

The situation:

The database has got the following columns:

- links (contains unique data)
- cl_link (contains the relation between links & cats)
- cats (cat. descriptions
- images (contains multiple images of one link)
- cfvalues (contains the values of the multiple custom fiels
- customfields (contains the multiple customfields)

I am using the following query, but the Joins are not working for me. Because I only get one image while sometimes there are multiple. And I only get one customfield instead of multiple and I get none cfvalues.

I guess something is wrong with the JOINS, but I am not sure. Can somebody help me out here?

The SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
rqypj_mt_links.link_name,
rqypj_mt_links.link_desc,
rqypj_mt_links.address,
rqypj_mt_links.city,
rqypj_mt_links.state,
rqypj_mt_links.country,
rqypj_mt_links.postcode,
rqypj_mt_links.telephone,
rqypj_mt_links.fax,
rqypj_mt_links.email,
rqypj_mt_links.website,
rqypj_mt_links.price,
rqypj_mt_links.lat,
rqypj_mt_links.lng,
rqypj_mt_links.zoom,
rqypj_mt_cats.cat_name,
rqypj_mt_images.filename,
rqypj_mt_cfvalues.value,
rqypj_mt_customfields.caption
FROM rqypj_mt_links
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cl
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_cl.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cats
ON rqypj_mt_cl.cat_id = rqypj_mt_cats.cat_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_images
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_images.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cfvalues
ON rqypj_mt_links.link_id = rqypj_mt_cfvalues.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_customfields
ON rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id = rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id LIMIT 100
```

Thanks in advance!
Jelte

Comment: Please describe exactly which results you expect and which results you get. For now, I'm voting to close.

Comment: Define "not working" **[edit]** your question and add some sample data, the actual result you get and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

your last condition doesn't look right:

```
 on rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id = rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id
```

translates to `1=1`

Shouldn't it be:

```
 on rqypj_mt_customfields.cf_id = rqypj_mt_cfvalues.cf_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you don't have an order by and are using limit.

Change it to

```
order by rqypj_mt_links.link_id, rqypj_mt_cl.cat_id
limit 100
```

and then your multiple pictures for the same link should be together.

---

Also please consider use of alias to make your code easier to read:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  links.link_name,
  links.link_desc,
  links.address,
  links.city,
  links.state,
  links.country,
  links.postcode,
  links.telephone,
  links.fax,
  links.email,
  links.website,
  links.price,
  links.lat,
  links.lng,
  links.zoom,
  cats.cat_name,
  images.filename,
  cfvalues.value,
  --custom.caption
FROM rqypj_mt_links links
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cl cl ON links.link_id = cl.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cats cats ON cl.cat_id = cats.cat_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_images images ON links.link_id = images.link_id
LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_cfvalues cfvalues ON links.link_id = cfvalues.link_id
--LEFT JOIN rqypj_mt_customfields custom ON custom.cf_id = custom.cf_id
ORDER BY links.link_id, cats.cat_id
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: And ordering the data was also a smart thing to (thanks Hogan). I find it a little bit hard to work with an alias for now. That will be the next step I guess.

Comment: alias is not hare you just put a name after any table name and then you can refer to the table by that name.  THUS everywhere you see `links` in my query it is exactly the same as if I'd typed `rqypj_mt_links`